# Print a thin HTML table on multiple columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a simple 2-column table that has A LOT of rows:

```
<table>
<tr><td>row 1 column1</td><td>row 1 column2</td></tr>
<tr><td>row 2 column1</td><td>row 2 column2</td></tr>
[500 more rows]
<tr><td>row 4999 column1</td><td>row 4999 column2</td></tr>
<tr><td>row 5000 column1</td><td>row 5000 column2</td></tr>
</table>
```

The columns are very thin, which means I can fit about 4 columns per page. (two table widths)

Is it possible to continue the table in another column on the same page, like the following:
[image]

(The next page would start with row 93)

Comment: what server-side technology are you using to display the web page? That would help

Comment: How is this a programming question? You can use the page button (bottom right) to increase the print content size.

Comment: What is ur back-end programming language?

Comment: I am using php echo to generate my table rows. Since the paper size is not defined, I can't decide when to move to the other column programmaticaly.

Comment: @clementgamache do you have to use a table?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use CSS columns this way:

```css
.col {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use this solution? There's no element with a 'col' id in the original question.

Comment: Does not work. Please explain how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print {
    body {
        column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
    }
}
```

Prints the website content in a two column layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size and the widths. You can also change the layout of the paper when printing, or if your printer is capable, use front and back sides of the paper.